# How to retain the maximum valued mspace, if found successively along with other mspaces

Tags: xslt

Please suggest for retaining **maximum** valued mspace among successively found mspaces [if text contained elements [mspace] found successively] some times in between there may be other elements like mrow will present, in such cases consecutive text contained spaces only to be consider. See me required out with comments for quick review.

Input XML:

```
    <article>

<math>
    <mspace>3</mspace>
    <mrow>
        <mspace>3</mspace>
        <mspace>2</mspace>
        <mo>(</mo>
        <mo>+</mo>
        <mo>)</mo>
        <mspace>3</mspace>
   </mrow>
    <mspace>9</mspace>
</math>

<math>
    <mo>[</mo>
    <mrow>
    <mspace>3</mspace>
    <mspace>2</mspace>
    <mspace>3</mspace>
    <mtext>log</mtext>
    <mn>3</mn>
    <mspace>2</mspace>
    </mrow>
    <mspace>2</mspace>
</math>

<math>
    <mspace>3</mspace>
    <mspace>3</mspace>
    <mn>4</mn>
    <mo>-</mo>
    <mi>a</mi>
    <mspace>2</mspace>
</math>


</article>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mspace">
    <xsl:variable name="var1" select="following::text()[normalize-space(.)!=''][1][generate-id(ancestor::math)=generate-id(current()/ancestor::math)]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="var2" select="preceding::text()[normalize-space(.)!=''][1][generate-id(ancestor::math)=generate-id(current()/ancestor::math)]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="var1a" select="following::text()[normalize-space(.)!=''][2][generate-id(ancestor::math)=generate-id(current()/ancestor::math)]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="var2a" select="preceding::text()[normalize-space(.)!=''][2][generate-id(ancestor::math)=generate-id(current()/ancestor::math)]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vPresent" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="vMax" select="max(($var1, $var2, $var1a, $var2a, $vPresent))"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$vPresent lt $var1 or $vPresent lt $var1a">
            <xsl:comment><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:comment>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$vPresent lt $var2 or $vPresent lt $var2a">
            <xsl:comment><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:comment>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$vPresent eq $var2 and $vPresent eq $var1a">
            <xsl:comment><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:comment>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="not($vPresent eq $var2) and $vPresent eq $var1">
            <xsl:comment><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:comment>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Required OutPut:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><article>

<math>
    <!--3-->
    <mrow>
        <mspace>3</mspace>
        <!--2-->
        <mo>(</mo>
        <mo>+</mo>
        <mo>)</mo>
        <!--3-->
   </mrow>
    <mspace>9</mspace>
</math>

<math>
    <mo>[</mo>
    <mrow>
    <!--3-->
    <!--2-->
    <mspace>3</mspace><!--To be required-->
    <mtext>log</mtext>
    <mn>3</mn>
    <mspace>4</mspace><!--To be required-->
    </mrow>
    <!--2-->
</math>

<math>
    <!--3-->
    <mspace>3</mspace><!--To be required-->
    <mn>4</mn>
    <mo>-</mo>
    <mi>a</mi>
    <mspace>2</mspace><!--To be required-->
</math>


</article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion using XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="math[descendant::mspace]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:variable name="max-elements" as="element(mspace)*">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="descendant::*[not(*)]" group-adjacent="boolean(self::mspace)">
        <xsl:if test="current-grouping-key()">
          <xsl:sequence select="current-group()[. = max(current-group())][last()]"/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
      <xsl:with-param name="max-elements" select="$max-elements" tunnel="yes"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mspace">
  <xsl:param name="max-elements" tunnel="yes"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test=". intersect $max-elements">
      <xsl:next-match/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:comment select="."/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It transforms your posted sample into

```
<article>
   <math><!--3-->
      <mrow>
         <mspace>3</mspace>
         <!--2-->
         <mo>(</mo>
         <mo>+</mo>
         <mo>)</mo>
         <!--3-->
      </mrow>
      <mspace>9</mspace>
   </math>
   <math>
      <mo>[</mo>
      <mrow><!--3--><!--2-->
         <mspace>3</mspace>
         <mtext>log</mtext>
         <mn>3</mn>
         <!--2-->
      </mrow>
      <mspace>2</mspace>
   </math>
   <math><!--3-->
      <mspace>3</mspace>
      <mn>4</mn>
      <mo>-</mo>
      <mi>a</mi>
      <mspace>2</mspace>
   </math>
</article>
```

Comment: Sir, great help from you. Working 100%.

Comment: Please, can u explain <xsl:for-each-group select="descendant::*[not(*)]" group-adjacent="boolean(self::mspace)"> coding.

Comment: The `select` expression `descendant::*[not(*)]` selects all descendant elements not having any child elements, so the elements like `mspace` or `mn` which contain the data and not further elements. The `group-adjacent` expression `boolean(self::mspace)` then allows us to identify adjacent `mspace` elements, the grouping key is true for adjacent `mspace`  elements and false for all other elements.

Comment: Sir, if element 'mspace' having alpha-numeric content like <mspace>3pts</mspace>, in such cases where to modify the code, Please suggest.

Comment: Consider to ask a new question explaining which output you want to have in that case.